# Delete .txt file when program closes/exits (X Button)

Tags: c++, file-io, exit, temporary

I have a program that will create a simple txt file in the same directory as the compiled .exe:

```
ofstream output("myfile.txt", ios::binary | ios::trunc);
```

At the end of my program, I have this to remove it:

```
remove("myfile.txt");
```

Both of these work well, however, I want the file deleted if the user closes the cmd window unexpectedly, accidently, or they end the process.

Comment: Might be worth starting a different process to watch for this one to end.

Comment: Interesting... can you elaborate or give a quick example? :)

Comment: On which operating system? Can't you make that output file a temporary file (e.g. with [tmpfile(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tmpfile.3.html), at least on Linux, MacOSX and other POSIX systems) ?

Comment: Window 7. I don't think so considering I have a completely seperate exe that uses this txt also. I want it written to the users system, then deleted when the program closes (maybe catch it when it crashes???)

Comment: Well, creation is easy enough with `WinExec`, `ShellExecute`, or `CreateProcess`. From what I can tell, it's not exactly trivial to make a robust watcher for crashes. Of course there are worse methods that are much easier, like checking whether it's still alive every few seconds.

Comment: your answer seems to be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390615/finally-in-c

Comment: @atk, Indeed, though crashes seem to be a necessary consideration as well, and when crashes are involved, a separate process is typically a good idea.

Comment: @chris: I imagine an exception handler would also be an important consideration.

Comment: @atk, Definitely, though the separate process would handle both. It comes down to choosing how picky you want to be and then only implementing it once :)

Comment: @user2356609, Wait, do you want this file deleted every time the process ends or only unexpectedly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to clean up your process is to register a function with `atexit`.

```
void clean_myfile {
    std::remove( "myfile.txt" );
}

int main() {
    std::ofstream output("myfile.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
    std::atexit( clean_myfile );
}
```

This will run if the process is exited gracefully, platform details notwithstanding.

Comment: This works great! I had to add ()  after the function declaration but it works when I close the window :)

Comment: I wish more people on SO gave simple answers like this :)

Comment: Notice that the `atexit` registered handler `clean_myfile` won't run if your program is killed, e.g. because of some segmentation violation.... As Potatoswatter answered, it will only run if the process is exiting *gracefully*....